# LINQ How to combine second item in Tuple after query using where on first item

Tags: c#, linq

```
 Tuple<int, double>[] obs1;
 Tuple<int, double>[] obs2;
```

What I'd like to do is create `Tuple<int, double>[] obs3`

which contains those `Tuple<int,double>` which have the same `int` in both `obs1` and `obs2` and then set the corresponding double as:

```
obs3[i].Item2 =  obs1[i].Item2 + obs2[i].Item2
```

I tried finding the relevant Tuples this way:

```
var obs3 = from o in obs1 where obs2.Contains(o) select o;
```

But then I don't know how to access and use the `Item2 double`, instead I just get a subset of `obs1`.

I keep getting downmarked for my questions.I'm hoping its because I've not tried presenting a first try at a solution.

Comment: I have two arrays of Tuples. Edited one line to show the index, perhaps that was confusing.

Comment: I looked at Zip but I don't see how to do both the selection on first Tuple Item and the operation on the second Item

Comment: What is supposed to happen if one of the input arrays has multiple tuples with the same `Item1` first coordinate `int` value? If this cannot be the case, maybe use some `Dictionary<int, double>` or `SortedDictionary<int, double>` or `SortedList<int, double>` or similar?

Comment: It should not happen unless I have a data error as input to the full program. The real problem has `Tuple<MyType,double>` where `MyType` contains a `char` and a `double`. I suppose I could use another ordered structure with unique elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can join both arrays on `Item1`

```
var query = from t1 in obs1
            join t2 in obs2 on t1.Item1 equals t2.Item1
            select Tuple.Create(t1.Item1, t1.Item2 + t2.Item2);

Tuple<int, double>[] obs3 = query.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using two loops like below (Not a Linq based solution)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tuple<int, double>[] obs1 = new Tuple<int, double>[] { new Tuple<int, double>(1, 1.2), new Tuple<int, double>(2, 1.5), new Tuple<int, double>(3, 2.2) };
        Tuple<int, double>[] obs2 = new Tuple<int, double>[] { new Tuple<int, double>(1, 2.1), new Tuple<int, double>(2, 5.1), new Tuple<int, double>(4, 2.2) }; ;
        Tuple<int, double>[] obs3 = new Tuple<int, double>[obs1.Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i < obs1.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < obs2.Count(); j++)
            {
                if (obs1[i].Item1 == obs2[j].Item1)
                {
                    obs3[i] = new Tuple<int, double>(obs1[i].Item1, obs1[i].Item2 + obs2[j].Item2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in obs3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item?.Item1 + "\t" + item?.Item2);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the new array `obs3` is not too long when you create it? Are you sure `obs2` will not contain multiple tuples with the same `Item1` since you do a `break;`?

Comment: Instead of `new Tuple<int, double>(x, y)` it is easier to read and write `Tuple.Create(x, y)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, that's right but it's an assumption made in starting...